# Passing Dynamic number of Parameters to Function

Tags: postgresql

I need to pass dynamic number of parameters to a function as well as their data types and then return a table having those parameters as fields. 
Is that possible to do that in postgres? 
Any idea or example is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that could probably be improved.

Beware of SQL injection!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_table(
   tabname text,
   VARIADIC coldef text[]
) RETURNS void
   LANGUAGE plpgsql STRICT AS
$$DECLARE
   l integer;
   i integer;
   sql text;
   sep text := '';
BEGIN
   l := array_upper(coldef, 1);

   IF l % 2 <> 0 THEN
      RAISE EXCEPTION 'Number of arguments must be odd';
   END IF;

   sql := 'CREATE TABLE ' || quote_ident(tabname) || '(';

   FOR i IN 1 .. l/2 LOOP
      sql := sql || sep || quote_ident(coldef[2*i-1]) || ' ' || quote_ident(coldef[2*i]);
      sep := ', ';
   END LOOP;

   sql := sql || ')';

   EXECUTE sql;
END;$$;
```

It can be used like this:

```
test=> SELECT create_table('tabname', 'col1', 'int4', 'col2', 'text');

test=> \d tabname
    Table "laurenz.tabname"
┌────────┬─────────┬───────────┐
│ Column │  Type   │ Modifiers │
├────────┼─────────┼───────────┤
│ col1   │ integer │           │
│ col2   │ text    │           │
└────────┴─────────┴───────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply